# url is not mapping with handler in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

i am getting this url by jquery

`localhost:8080/user/mak/1001?SelectName=mak&SelectId=1001&SelectReg=12e1`

my jsp form is

```
<form id="addForm" name="addForm" method="get"  action="">
```

and my handler

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/SelectName/SelectId",method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String getCategory(@RequestParam("SelectName")StringselectedName,
@RequestParam("SelectId")String selectedId, @RequestParam("SelectReg")String selectedReg,Model model, HttpSession session)
```

i want to show this url `localhost:8080/user/mak/1001`
and map with handler
can anyone suggest me how can i do this

Comment: Perhaps you need your application's context path? i.e. `localhost:8080/myapp/user/mak/1001`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem consists of two steps:

1. You should set your @RequestMapping's "value" attribute to 
   /user/{SelectName}/{SelectId}. The parentheses tell Spring MVC that
   you wish to make these parts of your URL dynamic.
2. You should replace your @RequestParam annotations with @PathVariable annotations.

More information on this topic can be found here: [Spring MVC reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping)